# Stanford CoreNLP memory leak

Tags: java, memory-leaks, stanford-nlp

In my application, I tokenize relatively large documents into sentences.
I have two distinct ways of splitting documents into sentences - one based on Simple CoreNLP Api and other based on a naive regexp.

Method based on CoreNLP:

```
public class CoreNLPSentenceTokenizer implements ITokenizer, Serializable {

    static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Override
    public List<String> getTokens(String s) {
        Document document = new Document(s);
        return document.sentences().stream().map(sent -> sent.text()).collect(Collectors.toList());
    }
}
```

Method based on naive regexp:

```
public class SentenceTokenizer implements ITokenizer {

    @Override
    public List<String> getTokens(String content) {
        return Arrays.asList(
                content.split("(\\.|\\?|\\!)"));
    }
}
```

After a while, when using CoreNLP-based tokenizer, I get OutOfMemoryError Exception. I decided to attach VisualVM to my application to see what's going on, which resulted in:

[image]

and huge memory allocation of edu.standford.nlp.pipeline.CoreNLPProtos$Token$Builder and edu.standford.npl.pipeline.CorenLPProtos$Token.

Then I replaced it with aforementioned naive tokenizer (the only part of code that I modified) and got these results:
[image]

which is more like what I'd expect, because I use the sentences to calculate hashes for indexing and discard them right after. The code based on this tokenizer has been running for about 18 hours now without out of memory exceptions and heap looks like this:

[image]

The solid area is the growing hash-based index (as expected) and spikes are most likely the sentences and other temporary objects allocated for hash computation.

I don't want to give up on CoreNLP since it gives me much better results than regexp tokenizer.

Comment: which version you are using ?? Using Version 3.6.0 or below might resolve the issue

Comment: @Nithin I am using the newest one from Maven - 3.8.0. I'll try some older version then, thanks.

Comment: @dkaras Did you ever get this leak resolved? I believe I am experiencing this as well... did downgrading to 3.6.0 help?  I am running 3.9.1.

Answer (score 0):

Could you try this without using the simple interface ?  That should get rid of the memory leak.  Make sure your code only builds the pipeline once when you build your tokenizer.

Also, Stanford CoreNLP 3.9.0 is in beta release right now, and we have added some new syntax to make it easier to use the traditional pipeline interface.  You can download 3.9.0 from our website or build from GitHub.

Though 3.9.0 is still a bit unstable and we will be putting up a new version soon.

Start with this traditional code and see if your memory leak goes away or not:

```
import edu.stanford.nlp.ling.*:
import edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.*;
import java.util.*;

// build the pipeline outside of your tokenize method when you
// initialize your tokenizer
Properties props = new Properties();
props.setProperty("annotators", "tokenize");
StanfordCoreNLP pipeline = new StanfordCoreNLP(props);

// use the pipeline when you want to tokenize
Annotation annotationToTokenize = new Annotation(s);
pipeline.annotate(annotationToTokenize);
List<CoreLabel> tokens = annotationToTokenize.get(CoreAnnotations.TokensAnnotation.class);
return tokens.stream().map(token -> token.word()).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: Is pipeline thread-safe, in particular the annotate() method? I am reusing single tokenizer across multiple threads.

Comment: Could you clarify for me, are you just running a batch process over a large corpus, or are you receiving documents and then tokenizing them.

Comment: I have a single Index object, which holds tokenizator as a filed. Outside of it I iterate over a large corpus of documents, get some small subset of it and for each document in subset I create thread that adds that document to Index. First step of addition to index is tokenization - this is also true for later searching in built index. I know that corenlp has a batch-like mode but using it would require rewriting lots of code of my application

Comment: I'm not positive about this, but I actually think it is *NOT* thread-safe to have 1 pipeline and call in multiple threads to tokenize.  You could just produce 1 pipeline per thread, the tokenizer does not have a large memory footprint.

Comment: https://stanfordnlp.github.io/CoreNLP/memory-time.html#depparse
The docs say a single pipeline should be used, but do not mention thread safety.

Comment: Is it possible to say definitively one way or the other, I remember reading individual annotators were thread safe?